# How do I star public transit locations?

Tags: google-maps

I commonly use a couple train stations when I come in and out of Chicago, is there a way to star them on the map so they are more visible when looking around on the Maps program on my phone?  They don't have a star to click like businesses.

By "train" I mean the local train; the 'L'.  Union Station stars just fine, but not the L stops (or bus stops).

[image]

Comment: Which phone OS are you using? Androids might support [highlights of businesses that are close to the station if you've done a review](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2125556/Google-Maps-Highlights-Google-Local-Recommendations).

Comment: Regarding your edit about "L" stops, I tested this out in Montreal with a local bus stop using Google+ as described in my answer below. It works for local bus stops. Google+ will find the location if you are near and you type it as it shows, e.g., "Quincy/Wells" in your screen shot above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 2013-05-26** With the [new version if Google Maps](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2418980,00.asp) a Google+ account is probably not needed.

**Edit tl;dr** You can star locations once you've *checked in* to them from Google+.

Here's a way I managed using my iPad and Google Maps in Safari. You have to have a Google+ account.

1. Write a status statement (like a "check in") from Google+ making sure you've specified the the location (i.e., the train station) when you enter the status. If Google+ can't find the location by default, you'll have to type it into the "Search for a nearby location" box.
2. Go to Google Maps in the Safari browser and make sure you're logged in to the same Google account you used for Google+ in step 1. Go to the "My Places" menu to show the list of your places. The train station you "checked in" from will show up in the list. You can now click the star icon of this location, and it'll show up in your map in Google Maps (Safari).

The following shows a bus stop called "Peel / Notre-Dame" in Montreal where I did a check-in using Google+, and it can now be starred in Maps under "My Places":
[image]

I know the Android version of Google Maps app is much more powerful than the iOS version (this won't work on iPad's Google Maps App - it has to be the Safari version). But the Google+ check-in seems to be the key to get the place to be "starable".

Comment: By the way, the "Check in" in Google+ doesn't have to be public. You can set its visibility only to yourself.

Comment: And you don't have to be there at all if you search.  This isn't perfect; clicking the star doesn't bring up the timetables, but probably the best that can be done (for now).

Comment: Interesting change: the new Google Maps interface now allows me to star any station, even those I wasn't able to add before.

Comment: @skolima I added this point in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed. In the web version of Google Maps:

- Search for the transit station. In this case, I looked for the Chicago Amtrak station.
- Click on the pin on the map.
- In the pop-up window, click on the star to the right of the location's name. Like so:

[image]

That's it; this location will now show up as a star when you browse Google Maps. If the transit stop doesn't have an easily searchable name like this, use an address, or an intersection; you can still do this. (I have my house starred like this on Google Maps.)

Comment: For some reason if you search for it and click the pinned location (e.g. A) it lets you star it; but if you click the train icon directly on the map you can't.  In any event, it doesn't work that well for the L stations (e.g. Quincy/Wells; see picture I added)

Comment: On the iPad, there are no popups (that I can see) in the Safari browser with Google Maps. @NickT what OS is that screen shot from?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator - It's on OSX.